# Powershell script for Exchange Server: Removing emails with cmdlets

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am writing a Powershell script for managing Exchange Distribution Groups and Public Folders.

In the Public Folder Management Console, I have created a Mail Enabled folder. In that folder's Properties, under the E-Mail Addresses tab, I want to remove all the occurrences of email addresses that contain *"Correspondence"* from the list.

My question is, how would you go about removing email addresses from a public folder's properties by using Powershell?

If you want to see a piece of code, here it is:

```
# create the new public folder

New-PublicFolder -Name $nextProjectName -Path "\Projets"

Add-PublicFolderClientPermission -Identity "\Projets\$nextProjectName"  -AccessRights CreateItems, ReadItems, CreateSubfolders, EditOwnedItems, FolderVisible, DeleteOwnedItems -User $nextProjectName

New-PublicFolder -Name "Correspondance" -Path "\Projets\$nextProjectName"

Enable-MailPublicFolder -Identity "\Projets\$nextProjectName\Correspondance"

$correspondanceAlias = $nextProjectCode.Substring(1,6)
Set-MailPublicFolder -Identity "\Projets\$nextProjectName\Correspondance" -Alias "bccp$correspondanceAlias" -DisplayName "bccp$correspondanceAlias"
```

Here is the screenshot showing in detail what I want to remove. The two SMTP addresses and the second one of the two X400 addresses.

[image: screenshot01]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. All I did is to repeat the cmdlet that sets the properties of the public folder to add the email addresses, so the *wrong* email addresses never appear.

```
$correspondanceAlias = $nextProjectCode.Substring(1,6)

Set-MailPublicFolder -Identity "\Projets\$nextProjectName\Correspondance" -Alias "bccp$correspondanceAlias" -DisplayName "bccp$correspondanceAlias"
Set-MailPublicFolder -Identity "\Projets\$nextProjectName\Correspondance" -EmailAddresses "bccp$correspondanceAlias@matricis.local", "bccp$correspondanceAlias@matricis.com"
```

Comment: I can't; I have to wait for two days.

Comment: Ok. :)  Its just that there are quite a lot of people that don't.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but I think this should work:

```
 foreach ($mailpf in get-mailpublicfolder){
    $addrs = $mailpf.emailaddresses | 
      where {$_.proxyaddressstring -notmatch "smtp:.*correspondence.*"}
    set-mailpublicfolder $mailpf.identity -emailaddresses $addrs -whatif
    }
```

Comment: Set-MailPublicFolder : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert value "
bccp11-034" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailPublicFolderIdP
arameter". Error: "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: objectId"

Comment: "Identity" doesn't seem to be the default value of the object.  I updated the script.